# Input string of unknown length

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, input

I wrote this program that replaces two spaces with an '*'.

How do I modify the code so that it does the same thing regardless of the string size? Is it even possible only using `putchar` and `getchar`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c;             
char buffer[256];  
int counter= 0;    
int i;             

int main()
{

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'&&c!=EOF) {  

    buffer[counter] =c;
    counter++;

    if (counter >=255) {
        break;
    }
 }

 for(i=0; i<256; i++) {

    if(buffer[i]== ' '&&buffer[i+1]==' ')
    { 

        buffer[i]= '*';

        putchar(buffer[i]); 

        i = i + 2; 

        continue; 
    }
    putchar(buffer[i]); 
}

putchar('\n'); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an *`int`*, which is actually important for the `EOF` check. You should probably also not put the `EOF` in the buffer. And remember that if the line entered is smaller than 256 character, then the remaining elements of `buffer` will be *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) and you should not use then when printing the input.

Comment: So I have edited the code but it is still not clear to me how i should implement the code to read and input string of unknown length

Comment: Your edit makes your while loop infinite. That `||` should be `&&`. Otherwise, to break the loop `c` would have to be `'\n'` *and* `EOF` simultaneously, which is impossible.

Comment: oh thanks. @WhozCraig Could you give me a hint on how to implement the code to do the same thing regardles of input string size?  I just don't understand how it should work

Comment: why are you even storing the complete input? wouldn't a ring-buffer of size 2 be enough for your use-case?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin so i shouldn't store input i should print it out right away?

Comment: @momonosuke that's how I would do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for just printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    char prev = EOF, curr;
    while ((curr =(char)getchar()) != '\n' && curr != EOF) 
            {  

                if(curr==' '&&prev==' ')
                {
                    curr = '*';
                    prev = EOF;

                }
                if (prev != EOF)
            putchar(prev);
        prev = curr;
            }
            putchar(prev);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `realloc` for actually changing the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main() {
        unsigned int len_max = 128;
        char *m = malloc(len_max);
        char c;             
        int counter= 0;    
        int i;
        int current_size = 256;
                printf("please input a string\n");
                while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) 
                {  

            m[counter] =(char)c;
            counter++;
            if(counter == current_size)
            {
                        current_size = i+len_max;
                m = realloc(m, current_size);
            }

                }


         for(i=0; i<counter; i++) 
         {

            if(m[i]== ' '&&m[i+1]==' ')
            { 
                m[i]= '*';
                putchar(m[i]); 
                i = i + 2; 
                continue; 
            }
            putchar(m[i]); 
        }

        putchar('\n'); 
        free(m);
        m = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but for my exercise I am only allowed to use putchar , getchar, while loops and ifs , I should have mentioned that earlier. Is it even possible ?

Comment: u mean u can't use `realloc`?

Comment: yeah i can't  I have been trying the whole day but I cant seem to get it right

Comment: i meant are you allowed to use `realloc`?

Comment: without `realloc` you can only define an string of very large size, and use that.

Comment: so that means I should define buffer instead of declaring it and then it should work?

Comment: yeah, like `char buffer[max_size]` ... do you just need to print or also store the whole string?

Comment: no I just need to print the whole string I don't need to store it

Comment: then a buffer of length 2 is enough for that

Comment: just use two variable: current and previous

Comment: thanks for your help  I just tried it now but I am not getting it right , how should i change my code to make it work?

Comment: my pleasure :) I also kept the code with `realloc` for future reference

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement doesn't require you to store the complete input in a buffer. The decision on what character to output only depends on the last two characters of input. Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // two variables for the last two input characters
  int c = EOF, last = EOF;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
      // if both are a space, store a single '*' instead
      if (c == ' ' && last == ' ')
        {
          c = '*';
          last = EOF;
        }
      // print the output, and shift the buffer
      if (last != EOF)
        putchar(last);
      last = c;
    }
  // take care of the last character in the buffer after we see EOF
  if (last != EOF)
    putchar(last);
}
```

no need for malloc and friends at all. This is a good expample for a problem that requires you to think carefully, before writing code, in order to not waste unnecessary resources on buffers.

Comment: how does last = c shift the buffer? I don't quite understand

Comment: well, maybe there's a smarter way to do that, but the idea is to store the current char of the input in `c`, and the one before that in `last`. `last = c` just means take the current one save it as last, before getting the next input from getchar.

Comment: the code is not important, it is only there to illustrate the point that a large buffer is not needed.

Comment: ok thx one final question is there away to modify my original code so that it prints output of unknown size? or can I just completely throw away my original code?

Comment: I believe you can probably drop your first loop and modify your second loop to work. :)

Comment: by drop you mean delete then I should only keep the for loop ? or I should move the while loop to the for loop and modify the for loop

Comment: I don't think you need two loops